# Selenium webdriver and Ruby. Standard directory and file structure

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to make my Selenium Webdriver Ruby tests suites, test cases, and test methods in separate files, so i can reuse the code between them. Right now I have separate ruby files for every test suite, containing every test case, and every method. This works, but its not the best way to maintain a lot of test suites constantly.

So I wanted to know what is the standard way to do this file separation, from a complete text file, to separate files for test cases and methods.

I found the following structure but don't understand how to use it with my requirements:

.

├── bin (not used)

├── data (not used)

├── doc (not used)

├── etc (I use it to store 3 different HOSTS files i overwrite depending on some parameters)

├── ext (not used)

├── lib (not used)

├── logs (keeps execution logs)

│  └── screenshots (keeps only failed test cases screenshots)

└── tests (test suites... with test data, test cases, and methods, in a 
single file per test suite)

Comment: Where you get this ?

Comment: Here: http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex46.html

Comment: I would use PageObject pattern instead.. and create whichever folder are necessary (logs/helpers/etc)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer I was looking for, because the directory I was more troubled about was the "tests/" directory, where I has all my tests, and the best way to have shared code between them, is to have a module with methods in a "tests/support" or "tests/shared" directory.